# Swift if directive quirk

Tags: swift

Suppose I have a complex chain of `if`s. Now I want to be sure that one of the conditions are triggered, so I add the final line to notify me when nothing was triggered.

```
if condition1 ...
else if condition2 ... 
else if condition3 ...
else print( "Ooops nothing triggered" )
```

Since I only want to print this in DEBUG mode, I wrap the final line

```
#if DEBUG
else print( "Ooops nothing triggered" )
#endif
```

and I get the strangest errors. "Closure expression is unused" and "Expected expression".

Here is some simple working code to illustrate with.

```
        let x = Int ( arc4random_uniform ( 100 ) ) - 50

        // This works
        if x > 0      { print ( "Positive" ) }
        else if x < 0 { print ( "Negative" ) }
        else          { print ( "Oops - neither" ) }

        // After adding the #if this does not compile
        if x > 0      { print ( "Positive" ) }
        else if x < 0 { print ( "Negative" ) }
        #if DEBUG
        else          { print ( "Oops - neither" ) }
        #endif
```

Obviously Swift's conditional compilation here fails. I wonder why and ask how to to do this so that the test is only applied in DEBUG mode?

FWIW I am not interested in e.g. using `switch` - the actual logic is complex. How to do this with `if`s and `else if`s if possible please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `#if`s don't really work like those preprocessor directives in C. They

According to the [grammar](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_conditional-compilation-block), the syntax of these directives are the following:

```
if-directive-clause → if-directive compilation-condition statements(opt)
elseif-directive-clauses → elseif-directive-clause elseif-directive-clauses(opt)
elseif-directive-clause → elseif-directive compilation-condition statements(opt)
else-directive-clause → else-directive statements(opt)
if-directive → #if
elseif-directive → #elseif
else-directive → #else
endif-directive → #endif
```

Note that an `if-directive-clause` consists of `#if`, then a `compilation-condition`, then some `statements`. Not just anything, but *statements*.

```
else { print ( "Oops - neither" ) }
```

is not a statement (or a list of statements).

---

How about putting the `#if` inside the `else` block? That is guaranteed to be a `statements`:

```
if x > 0      { print ( "Positive" ) }
else if x < 0 { print ( "Negative" ) }
else          { 
#if DEBUG 
    print ( "Oops - neither" ) 
#endif 
}
```

Comment: Thanks that answers the question of why it fails. Is there any better way of doing it? The way you suggest will work but will result in some left-over code when not in DEBUG mode? Or will that empty else then be optimised away?

Comment: @skaak From my experimentation on https://godbolt.org, They compile to the same assembly, even without `-O`!

Comment: @skaak ...not to mention that you _typically_ have bigger problems to worry about than empty `else` blocks...

Comment: True ... thanks - I appreciate it. Will do as you suggest but I miss my ol' honest C ```#if``` wrappers ...